# getting data from an array test using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, protractor

I created a array with objects, which has different values, i needed to test the content of a specific array so i used

```
var child  =   element.all(by.css('.col.col-top.col-67')),element.all(by.css('.ng-binding'));

expect(child.get(1)).toEqual('HAL 9000');
```

this sends error msg in my terminal "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Abort trap: 6" 
actually i need to check that hal 9000 is been displayed in the html page

```
<a class="item-content" ng-href="#/lead/details/1/" target="_self" href="#/lead/details/1/">

                <div class="row" style="height: 35px; width: 100%; margin-left:-10px; margin-top: -10px; margin-right: 0px; padding: 0px"> 
                    <div class="col col-top col-67">
                        <h2 class="ng-binding">HAL 9000</h2>
                        <br>
                        <h4 style="font-weight: normal; margin-top: -15px" class="ng-binding">Jupiter &nbsp; Feb 10, 2025 </h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col col-center col-10 col-offset-25" style="margin-right: -10px">
                        <a href="tel:9876543210" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                            <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline" style="font-size: 36px"></i>                       
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-center col-20" style="margin-left: 15px">
                        <a href="mailto:hai@spaceodyssey.com?Subject=Hi;" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                            <i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline" style="font-size: 36px;"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.all()` cannot be attached to an instance of `element.all()`. Moreover you are using a `,` instead of a `.` Try dividing `.ng-binding` in a way such that you can get it without need to use an array. If you have to get all elements under `.col.col-top.col-67` then use `.each()` function to get each div with that class and then use each div to get all elements with `.ng-binding`. Here's how -

```
element.all(by.css('.col.col-top.col-67')).each(function(eachDiv){ //get each div with the specified class
    var child = eachDiv.$$('.ng-binding'); //get all the elements with ng-binding under each div
    expect(child.get(1)).toEqual('HAL 9000'); //add your expectations
});
```

**NOTE:** When you use `each()` it loops through all the elements using that element locator just like a `for` loop. Assuming that there are many elements with the class `.col.col-top.col-67` and many elements under it with class `.ng-binding`.

If at all there is a single element then you don't have to use `element.all()` in the above code. Hope it helps

Comment: thank you but i am getting err msg " TypeError: eachDiv.element.all is not a function"

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan updated answer. Let me know if you still get any error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help i just slightly modify the above code given by Girish Sortur

```
            var lItems = element.all(by.css('.col.col-top.col-67'));
            var child = lItems.get(1).$$('.ng-binding'); //get all the elements with ng-binding under each div
            expect(child.get(0).getText()).toEqual('HAL 9000'); //add your expectations
```